# UIWebView Deleting tags from html

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview, tags

For example I have returned html in UIWebView text:

`<div id="id1"><p>Some Text</p></div>`
`<div id="id2"><p>SOME TEXT</p></div>`

And I need to delete tag with id="id2", and return to user, how can I do this?

Comment: could you please help in how to add tags in existing HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is call js code which removes that element after content is loaded.

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"var element = document.getElementById('%@'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);",
         @"id2",
];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand]
```